# How can I annotate a Django queryset with a count in a way that's conditional to some property of each item in the queryset?

Tags: django

Sorry about the title, I think some pseudo-code will clarify the question:

```
class Image(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)

class Group(Model):
    members = ForeignKey(User)
    images = ForeignKey(Image)
    autosubmission = BooleanField()
```

As you can see, we have a `Group`, consisting of some `members` and some `images`.

If the group is `autosubmission` then members don't submit images manually to it, but all images belonging to a member automatically show up in the group.

If the group is **not** `autosubmission` then the members need to submit the images manually, and they end up in the `images` `ForeignKey`.

Now, I want to have a queryset that's annotated by the number of images the the group.

```
Group.objects.all().annotate(num_images = Count('images'))
```

Obviously, the code above only works for groups that are **not** `autosubmission`, i.e. the images are actually in the `images` relation.

So how can I annotate the queryset so it works both for groups that are `autosubmission` and groups that are not?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the images of a the group if its `autosubmission` ? because I don't see the `images` field in the Group to be of any help in this case.

Comment: Then I do `Image.objects.filter(user__in = group.members.all())`